# Simple iText7 v8.0.1 .net6 app works fine on Win10 but crashes on macOS Ventura with .net6

Tags: .net-core, itext, cross-platform, itext7

The console code below is intended to produce a password-protected copy of input PDF file pdfMaster.pdf and write it into the same directory as the input file.  It works perfectly when I run it on Win10, but on macOS Ventura the pdfDoc.close(); statement crashes the program with the message that follows the code below.

I thought it might be that I was trying to create a file at all on the Mac system, but if I comment out the pdfDoc.close(); statement, the call to File.WriteAllText that follows it works fine and does create its test file correctly.

All of the dlls and other files associated with this program are in the same Mac directory and I run my application in that directory using "Terminal".  I've tried running it with both

```
dotnet Watermark.dll
```

and

```
sudo dotnet Watermark.dll
```

but the results are the same.  All I can come up with is that either I'm missing something in what I'm doing, or pdfDoc.close() or .net6 on the Mac is doing something funky.

Because I'm able to create a file using the standard File.WriteAllText approach, I'm wondering if there might be some way in iText7 to cause the bytes resulting from the encryption to be written to a byte array instead of a file.  I could then simply write that array to a file using File.WriteAllBytes instead.

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using System.Text;

namespace Watermark
{
   internal class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Watermark!");

         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"pdfMaster.pdf");

         byte[] userPW = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My");
         byte[] ownerPW = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PW");

         WriterProperties props = new WriterProperties().
            SetStandardEncryption(userPW, ownerPW,
            EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING,
            EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 |
            EncryptionConstants.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
         
         PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(@"pdfOUT_PW.pdf", props);
         PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
         pdfDoc.Close();

         File.WriteAllText("pdfOutputTest.pdf", "File.WriteAllText test\n");
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the macOS message:

```
admin@Macs-Mac watermark % dotnet watermark.dll
realpath(watermark.dll) failed: Operation not permitted
getcwd() failed: Operation not permitted
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Parser' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.AddCommandParser' threw an exception.
 ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Operation not permitted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Sys.GetCwdHelper(Byte* ptr, Int32 bufferSize)
   at Interop.Sys.GetCwd()
   at System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommonOptions.DefaultToCurrentDirectory[T](Argument`1 arg)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.AddCommandParser..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Parser..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently pdfDoc.close attempts to write the specified output file to somewhere other than the execution directory on macOS if no path is specified.  Maybe this is documented somewhere?  After a lot of wasted time and frustration I fixed the problem by specifying

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(@"./pdfOUT_PW.pdf", props);
```

instead of

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(@"pdfOUT_PW.pdf", props);
```

To me this seems totally inconsistent with the reader code below, which assumes the file is in the execution directory without specifying ./ in front of the name.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"pdfMaster.pdf");
```